# Make CreateProcess get stdin from a string

Tags: c++, windows

Pretty simple, but can't really find anything on how to do this. Anyone have any tips or helpful links? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want an [anonymous pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe).

If so, I'd suggest you have a look at [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: +1, but note that the code in the MSDN article will block/deadlock if the input from/output to the program is too large.  You really need a separate thread or non-blocking I/O to use a pipe like this.